# Excel VBA - Loop is not properly deleting the last row in a table

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I've been working on a macro that deletes the row in a table if the values in the table's Column A do not match any of the values in another separate Column B. Currently, my code isn't deleting the last row properly, and I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

Here is my current code:

```
Sub Stuff()
    Dim rCell As Range, ColumnA As Range, ColumnB As Range
    Dim rowPoint As Integer

    Set ColumnA = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Table2[Column1]") 
    Set ColumnB = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Table1")

    rowPoint = ColumnA.Count

    On Error Resume Next

    For i = rowPoint To 1 Step -1
        For Each rCell In ColumnA
            If Application.CountIf(ColumnB, rCell.Value) = 0 Then rCell.Rows.Delete

        Next rCell
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the `For i = ... Next i` loop meant to do? `i` is never referenced in the body of the loop and the `For Each rCell ... Next rCell` loop seems sufficient on its own

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of a noob at this. I cleaned up the script a little bit afterwards so that it was actually properly looping backwards through the range. It was still leaving a random row that wasn't supposed to be there. But android_newbie's comment regarding xlShiftUp got this macro working...though I'm still not entirely clear why.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What do you mean when you say that the last row is not being deleted properly?

Is it being deleted and the formatting is a problem or the last row does not get deleted at all?

If it is a formatting problem then you could use

```
If Application.CountIf(ColumnB, rCell.Value) = 0 Then rCell.Rows.Delete xlShiftUp
```

This will delete the cell only in that column and moved the rows below the deleted cell upwards without changing the structure of the other columns.

Comment: Omg xlShiftUp nailed it on the head. Thank you so much.

Comment: you know, you could delete all the rows without a loop in one step just by using SpecialCells

Comment: @user2146675: If this answer solved your problem, please mark it answer by clicking on the checkmark!